# Ошибка при не установке адаптера Android

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, многопоточность

Порядок действий:

1)Кнопка вызывает **click_get();**

2)Создается Поток **myAs**

3)В **doInBackground** получаю данные и парсю

4)В **onPostExecute** Если поле **found == data** тогда устанавливаю адаптер для **ListView** , А если **found == empty** не устанавливаю адаптер.

5)Первый раз при клике на Item - таблица **не** пуста, и имеет **found == data** и ее загружает в **onPostExecute**

6)Второй раз при клике на Item - таблица пуста, и имеет**found == empty** Все идет нормально, данные с пустой таблицы берутся (null,null,null) но это нормально.

А вот в методе **onPostExecute** стоит проверка, если **found = empty** то не устанавливать адаптер для **ListView**, ведь ничего страшного что **doInBackground** собрал пустые данные, главное что адаптер не устанавливаем.

**Вот тут ошибка**, если проверяет что нету данных и не ставит адаптер, то выводит ошибку и закрывает приложение. Где-то читал что надо обновлять список, но зачем. я ведь данные не изменяю, и адаптер не устанавливаю.

Код ошибки:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class default.MyActivity$ItemAdapter)]

Создаю поток:

```
public void click_get(View view) throws InterruptedException {
myAsync myAs = new myAsync();
myAs.execute();
}
```

в ***myAs*** собираю данные с сервера в формате ***JSON***;

```
 class myAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... param) {

        productsList.clear();
        HttpResponse data = null;
        String parseData = "";
        String id_p;
        String name_p;

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet http = new HttpGet(url);
        //03iht0u7jvt0pphkt9
        try {
            data = client.execute(http);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        HttpEntity entity = data.getEntity();
        int i;
        try {
            parseData  = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            json = new JSONArray(parseData);
            type = json.getJSONObject(0).get("type").toString();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        list.add(url);

        if(type.indexOf("cat") > -1){
                    for (i = 0;i< json.length(); i++){
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        try {

                            map.put("name",json.getJSONObject(i).getString("name_cat"));
                            map.put("id_cat",json.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_cat"));
                            map.put("found",json.getJSONObject(i).getString("found"));
                            productsList.add(map);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
                else{
                    for (i = 0;i< json.length(); i++){
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        try {
                            map.put("name",json.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                            map.put("price",json.getJSONObject(i).getString("price"));
                            map.put("count",json.getJSONObject(i).getString("count"));
                            map.put("description",json.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                            map.put("id",json.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                            map.put("found",json.getJSONObject(i).getString("found"));
                            map.put("pl","Цена:");
                            map.put("cl","Количество:");
                            productsList.add(map);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
            }

        return null;
    }

        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

               if(productsList.get(0).get("found").indexOf("empty") != -1){
           productsList.clear();

               }else{
                   l("isFOUND");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    if (type.indexOf("cat") > -1){

                            setContentView(R.layout.list_view_cat);
                            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), productsList, R.layout.list_view_cat, new String[]{"name"}, new int[]{R.id.edit1,});

                            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exlist);
                            lv.setOnItemClickListener(onListClickItem);
                            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } else {
                        setContentView(R.layout.list_view_pro);

                        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), productsList, R.layout.list_view_pro, new String[]{"name", "price", "count", "pl", "cl"}, new int[]{R.id.pro_name, R.id.price, R.id.count, R.id.price_label, R.id.count_label});
                        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exlist_pro);
                        lv.setOnItemClickListener(onListClickItem);
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }}});}}}
```

И при клике на любой элемент вызываю функцию:
@Override

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){

        if(type.indexOf("cat") > -1){

            url = DOMAIN+"/"+API_DIR+"/"+INPUT_FILE+"?table_name="+productsList.get(i).get("id_cat");
            try {

                click_get(null);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();}}}
```

Comment: у Вас productsList является данными адаптера. Если Вы его модифицируете (а clear - это тоже модификация!) Вы обязаны позвать `notifyDatasetChanged`.

Comment: Это я пробовал, но у него нету этого метода. Тем более ProductList это не адаптер, а параметр для адаптера.

Comment: Код пока что не читал, но  
`((BaseAdapter)listview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();`  
Должно сработать.  
P.S. Мы прям как будто чувствуем друг друга, я сюда только что зашёл, чтоб задать вопрос про адаптер)

Comment: Ну да, я пробовал, только у меня SimpleAdapter, а там нет таких методов. Попробовал ещё один вариант, если нет данных, просто тогда в качестве адаптера устанавливать той адаптер, который был во время клика.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте listview.invalidateViews();

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, спасибо х2, очень долго решение подбирал, разные методы...... а тут вот как.

Comment: Вы только будьте аккуратны: старайтесь не допускать прокрутки списка при вызове invalidateViews(), а то может случиться краш.

Comment: Создал кучу пунктов(~40) и кручу-верчу, крашов нету).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html